# Image Not Display in Custom Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, image

I Have To Create One Custom Grid.
in That Grid Image Have Field .
But Image Not Displayed There.

**C:\xampp2\htdocs\testmagento\app\code\local\Rushikesh\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Grid.php**  Code.

```
$this->addColumn('image', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Image'),
            'index' => 'image',
            'renderer' => 'Rushikesh_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Image',
        ));
```

**C:\xampp2\htdocs\testmagento\app\code\local\Rushikesh\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Renderer\Image.php** Code

```
Class Rushikesh_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Image extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
        {
            $value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
            return '<img src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$value.'"  width="80" />';
        }
}
```

**ModuleController.php**

```
public function saveAction()
    {
        if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
            if(isset($_FILES['fileinputname']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['fileinputname']['tmp_name']))) {
              try {
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('fileinputname');
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // or pdf or anything


                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

                // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file in a folder the magento way
                // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file directly in the $path folder
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ;

                $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['fileinputname']['name']);

                $data['fileinputname'] = $_FILES['fileinputname']['name'];
              }catch(Exception $e) {

              }
            }else {      

                if(isset($data['fileinputname']['delete']) && $data['fileinputname']['delete'] == 1)
                    $data['image_main'] = '';
                else
                    unset($data['fileinputname']);
            }  
            try {
                $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                if(isset($postData['links'])){
                    $products = Mage::helper('adminhtml/js')->decodeGridSerializedInput($data['links']['products']); //Save the array to your database
                }
                //var_dump($postData['links']);
                //exit;
                $moduleModel = Mage::getModel('module/module');

                $moduleModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->setTitle($postData['title'])              
                    ->setCId($postData['c_id'])
                    ->setTitle2($postData['title2'])
                    ->setContent($postData['content'])                  
                    ->setStatus($postData['status'])                    
                    ->setCreatedTime(time()) //Created Date-Time
                    ->save();

                /* Short Method For Saving Data In To Database */

                        /* $makemodelModel = Mage::getModel("module/module")    
                                ->addData($postData)
                                ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))
                                ->save(); */

                /* Short Method For Saving Data In To Database */

                var_dump($products);
                //var_dump($postData);exit;
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setModuleData(false);

                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setModuleData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }

        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
```

When Show Inspect Element in browser.

[image]

Comment: Module Name is  " Rushikesh_Module "

Comment: what is the value of your image field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving the image file name and for this you have to change some code like :

```
$moduleModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
       ->setTitle($postData['title'])              
       ->setCId($postData['c_id'])
       ->setTitle2($postData['title2'])
       ->setContent($postData['content'])                  
       ->setStatus($postData['status'])                    
       ->setCreatedTime(time()) //Created Date-Time
       ->setImage($data['fileinputname']) // Add this line according to your image field name
       ->save();
```

Comment: in database image value insert is Zero

Comment: You have to check the image is getting uploaded or not. Also check the image field type in database, it bust be varchar.

Comment: Yes u r right, its workes now

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem in your save action. Try below code.

```
<?php

public function saveAction() {
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

            if(isset($_FILES['filename']['name']) && $_FILES['filename']['name'] != '') {
                try {   
                    /* Starting upload */   
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('filename');

                    // Any extention would work
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

                    // Set the file upload mode 
                    // false -> get the file directly in the specified folder
                    // true -> get the file in the product like folders 
                    //  (file.jpg will go in something like /media/f/i/file.jpg)
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                    // We set media as the upload dir
                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS ;
                    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['filename']['name'] );

                } catch (Exception $e) {

                }

                //this way the name is saved in DB
                $data['filename'] = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
            }


            $model = Mage::getModel('module/module');       
            $model->setData($data)
                ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

            try {
                if ($model->getCreatedTime == NULL || $model->getUpdateTime() == NULL) {
                    $model->setCreatedTime(now())
                        ->setUpdateTime(now());
                } else {
                    $model->setUpdateTime(now());
                }   

                $model->save();
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('module')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
                    return;
                }
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('module')->__('Unable to find item to save'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

?>
```

Then write below code in your `image.php` file

```
<?php

Class Rushikesh_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Image extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $img = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        if($img && strpos($img, 'no_selection') !== 0) {
            return sprintf('<img src="%s" width="60px" />', Mage::getBaseUrl('media').$img);
        }

        return '';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: in my save action all data should stored in database but only image name should not stored in database

Comment: $moduleModel = Mage::getModel('module/module');
                    
                $moduleModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->setTitle($postData['title'])
        ->setFileinputname($_FILES['fileinputname']['name'])          
     ->setCId($postData['c_id'])
                    ->setTitle2($postData['title2'])
                    ->setContent($postData['content'])     
                    ->setStatus($postData['status'])     
     ->setCreatedTime(time()) //Created Date-Time
                    ->save();

Comment: here is my code that strore all data into database

Comment: ->setFileinputname($_FILES['fileinputname']['name'])           I use that for store image